# Backup, without having to reinstall 3rd party programs?

Tags: linux, backup

Say I back up the `/` partition with `cpio` and the disk fails. Would I have to reinstall all third party programs if I used `cpio` to restore the `/` on a new disk? Or is backing `/` up enough to keep them installed.

Or, is the only way to do this to clone the disk with `dd`? I don't have a disk large enough to clone the servers partitions, so cloning won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of goes without saying that if you backup and restore everything, then everything will be there.  Also `cpio` is an odd choice, `tar` is better.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: Well, cpio syntax is shorter (for doing backups).

Comment: @djangofan, how do you figure?  You have to run a separate `find` process to generate the file list and pipe it to `cpio`.

Comment: http://rightsock.com/~kjw/Ramblings/tar_v_cpio.html

Comment: @djangofan, from 2001 and largely out of date/incorrect: 1) tar also preserves hard links, 2) filename limitation is a non issue, 3) tar also preserves timestamps, 4) tar also has switches to include/exclude by pattern, 5) multiple concurrent network streams slows things down, not speeds them up.

Comment: touché .  Ok, well obviously I have a habit of believing anything I read on the internet.